# Why are empty ".z.*" files being created in my home folder and can I safely remove them?

Tags: files

In my home folder, I have realized that plenty of `.z.*` files are being created, and they are all empty. I have no idea which process created them.

What might be the reason for all these files being created, and is it safe to remove them?

```bash
$ cat .z.*
$ ls .z.*
.z.28    .z.3504  .z.6019  .z.9240   .z.12471  .z.15266  .z.18282  .z.20997  .z.24111  .z.26818  
.z.40    .z.3511  .z.6020  .z.9293   .z.12495  .z.15268  .z.18285  .z.21031  .z.24129  .z.26847  
.z.145   .z.3533  .z.6039  .z.9305   .z.12516  .z.15303  .z.18292  .z.21051  .z.24136  .z.26874  
.z.217   .z.3584  .z.6049  .z.9316   .z.12548  .z.15337  .z.18348  .z.21099  .z.24143  .z.26900  
.z.284   .z.3599  .z.6107  .z.9326   .z.12570  .z.15361  .z.18360  .z.21102  .z.24208  .z.26909  
.z.342   .z.3611  .z.6125  .z.9353   .z.12587  .z.15378  .z.18370  .z.21103  .z.24265  .z.26913  
.z.357   .z.3658  .z.6138  .z.9370   .z.12613  .z.15438  .z.18371  .z.21120  .z.24292  .z.26932  
.z.360   .z.3668  .z.6152  .z.9396   .z.12676  .z.15452  .z.18398  .z.21141  .z.24303  .z.27007  
.z.397   .z.3702  .z.6159  .z.9428   .z.12682  .z.15468  .z.18399  .z.21181  .z.24316  .z.27040  
.z.406   .z.3744  .z.6173  .z.9443   .z.12685  .z.15476  .z.18419  .z.21219  .z.24339  .z.27042  
.z.415   .z.3784  .z.6204  .z.9452   .z.12712  .z.15491  .z.18483  .z.21278  .z.24341  .z.27062  
.z.500   .z.3818  .z.6317  .z.9467   .z.12748  .z.15561  .z.18484  .z.21299  .z.24344  .z.27076  
.z.551   .z.3870  .z.6329  .z.9557   .z.12763  .z.15575  .z.18490  .z.21339  .z.24363  .z.27085  
.z.605   .z.3886  .z.6339  .z.9594   .z.12782  .z.15583  .z.18494  .z.21384  .z.24373  .z.27124  
.z.606   .z.3887  .z.6369  .z.9605   .z.12791  .z.15587  .z.18501  .z.21399  .z.24399  .z.27127
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are left-overs from [`z`](https://github.com/rupa/z), a fancy `cd` replacement. You might have this as an [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) plugin. `z` maintains a `~/.z` file, and the numbered versions are created when that file is updated; but they are supposed to be deleted automatically.

I used to see this too, but haven’t recently; things might have improved with recent versions of `z`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably defined an alias `env` in your shell, which hides `/usr/bin/env`. z.sh creates temporary files named .z.$RANDOM. `env` is used to `rm`  or `mv` these files. I had the same problem and it was gone, after I patched z.sh to use `/usr/bin/env` (instead of just `env`). And don't forget to `source z.sh` after the patch.